# Extract XMLdata file to Mysql with php script, into 2 tables linked by foreign Key

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I need to script in php to extract data from xml file and insert into a mysql database

My XML file with the following nodes:

< dest> "customer data"
<det nItem "x"> "list of purchased products, can be 1 or more products"

I cann't separate the data from this xml in 2 tables of my mysql database,
linked by foreign key, ex: "tbl_customer", id_dest (customer and main data)
and "tbl_products", id_det, data of the purchased items and connected to id_dest.

XML example:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            -<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="4.00">
            -<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
            -<infNFe versao="4.00" Id="NFe352XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
            +<ide>
            +<emit>
            -<dest>
               <CNPJ>222222000108</CNPJ>
               <xNome>XPTO ENTERPRISE</xNome>
               -<enderDest>
                   <xLgr>R XPTO</xLgr>
               <nro>134</nro>
                   <xBairro>PARQUE JACATUBA</xBairro>
               </enderDest>
               <indIEDest>1</indIEDest>
               <IE>22222222222</IE>
               <email>adm@hotmail.com</email>
            </dest>
                -<det nItem="1">
                    -<prod>
                    <cProd>141034166</cProd>
                    <xProd>GRAXEIRA RETA 1-8POL NPT 27F 7-16POL</xProd>
                    <NCM>84879000</NCM>
                    <CFOP>5102</CFOP>
                    </prod>
                    -<imposto>
                    -<ICMS>
                    -<ICMSSN102>
                    <orig>0</orig>
                    <CSOSN>102</CSOSN>
                </det>
                +<det nItem="2">
                +<det nItem="3">
                .
                .
                .
```

Expectation of table "tbl_products":

```
               id_det | id_dest | nItem    | cProd   | xProd                                | NCM
                  1   |  1      | 1        |14103416 | GRAXEIRA RETA 1-8POL NPT 27F 7-16POL | 84879000
                  2   |  1      | 2        |141054174| GRAXEIRA CURVA 45 GRAUS 1-8POL       | 84879000
                  3   |  1      | 3        |141054190| GRAXEIRA CURVA 90 GRAUS 1-8POL       | 84879000
```

Thanks!